# Is it possible to add a filter to a Kibana Dashboard

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I have a dashboard of graphs all based on the same saved search. Is it possible to set add a filter to the dashboard, so I can easily toggle it on and off?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it by following [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html#field-filter) doc.

Comment: That only covers adding a filter from the search results, not from a dashboard.

Comment: It can be applied on visualization page and dashboard page by `pinning` it. You will find `pin` option in `filter actions` menu.